# AttributeError: 'ParsedRequirement' object has no attribute 'req'

Tags: python, docker, travis-ci

I have docker file with one layer as

```
RUN python setup.py develop
```

I am using a mutli-stage build with three stages and this is the stage one all the stages have the same base image, though I don't think this is a problem with dockerfile but seems to be a problem with python and the way it is executed
working on the base image `python:3.7-slim`
I am building this dockerfile on Travis CI with this below
Version info on Travis:

```
docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:42:38 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      17.09.0-ce
 API version:  1.32 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   afdb6d4
 Built:        Tue Sep 26 22:41:20 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I get this below error as

```
AttributeError: 'ParsedRequirement' object has no attribute 'req'
```

Surprisingly I am able to have this working on My mac machine with docker version `19.03.2`
Here is my `setup.py` file

```py
import os
import shutil
import inspect
import platform
from setuptools import setup
import setuptools
try:
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements

EMAIL_CONF = 'email.conf'
DL_CONF = 'dl.conf'
LINUX_CONFDIR = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.config/bassa/'
WIN_CONFDIR = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/%app_data%/bassa/'
OSX_CONFDIR  = os.path.expanduser('~') + '/.config/bassa/'

# Utility function to read the README file.
def read(file_name):
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), file_name)).read()

base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
requirements_path = os.path.join(base_dir, 'requirements.txt')

install_reqs = parse_requirements(requirements_path, session=False)

requirements = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]

### Set configs ###
if platform.system() == 'Linux':
    configdir = LINUX_CONFDIR
elif platform.system() == 'Windows':
    configdir = WIN_CONFDIR
elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
    configdir = OSX_CONFDIR
if not os.path.exists(configdir):
    os.makedirs(configdir)

email_conf_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + "/" + EMAIL_CONF
dl_conf_location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe()))) + "/" + DL_CONF
shutil.copyfile(email_conf_location, configdir + EMAIL_CONF)
shutil.copyfile(dl_conf_location, configdir + DL_CONF)

###/ Set configs ###

setup(
   ...
)
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please show the requirements.txt file and confirm the line where the error is occurring.

Comment: @Ronald requirements.txt is a simple list of dependencies. I guess its working fine on my machine but it does not work on a docker setup that to on Travis, but one more point is it works on travis too when I append /bin/bash -c to the RUN layer in the starting

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Update:

#### * Please note that updating pip and pip-tools is not supported in my case. Then the workaround in my answer will help.

#### * If updating pip and pip-tools to compatible version is supported then refer to [Gnnr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64173656/10069193) or [Heapify's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68291644/10069193)

I got the fix finally \o/

```
install_reqs = parse_requirements(requirements_path, session=False)
```

At first, I have inspected what install_reqs was on Travis by simply logging it and found that it was a list of ParsedRequirement objects. I also found that this class is defined in `req_file.py`. I have gone to check the source code for `req_file.py` [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/549a9d11a1f269206809b8276bee41abbc7cb533/src/pip/_internal/req/req_file.py#L81) on GitHub. I found that there was no such attribute called `req` but instead it is `requirement`. So there were two versions of `parse_requirements` function so I handled this using a try and except block.

```
# Generator must be converted to list, or we will only have one chance to read each element, meaning that the first requirement will be skipped.
requirements = list(requirements) 
try:
    requirements = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]
except:
    requirements = [str(ir.requirement) for ir in install_reqs]
```

Now it is compatible with both the versions \0/

Comment: Don't ever use bare `except` - always catch a specific exception (`AttributeError` I guess)!

Comment: You solution is not going to work, or cause VERY DANGEROUS BUGS, unless you first run `install_reqs = list(install_reqs)`. The reason is that `install_reqs` is a generator, which means that the first element will be gone in the exception's first iteration. The installation will think it will have finished successfully, while you will miss the first prerequirement!

Comment: Please, fix discrepancy in example code: install_reqs vs requirements

Comment: @MarekGrác what exactly was your comment about, can you elaborate?

Comment: @MehantKammakomati You create var requirements to be list instead of generator. But install_reqs is filled with generator and 'requirements' is undefined at that line.

Answer (score 3):

I came across a very similar problem with the same error message. It occurred when working with pip-tools / pip-compile / pip-sync.
The problem was probably related to non-compatible versions of pip and pip-tools and was resolved by updating both pip and pip-tools.

Resolving these problems could remove the necessity of the workaround in the [answer of Mehant Kammakomati](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114945/attributeerror-parsedrequirement-object-has-no-attribute-req/62127548#62127548).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yet the problem is updating pip tools isn't supported so this work around is must ✌️

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not directly related to the error in Docker, but I was getting the same error and came across this post when I Googled and would like to add my two cents -

This error is definitely related to `pip`, `pip-tools` and `python` versions not being compatible. I looked at the compatible versions [here](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools#versions-and-compatibility) and matched my project with them and the error was resolved.

I'd say, try this first before you do anything else

Comment: I have updated the question in support of your answer as I believe there could be devs with your setting and this would be a good fix!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround:

```py
try:
    # newest versions.
    # pip>=21.x.x
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
        install_req_from_parsed_requirement,
    )
except ImportError:
    # pip<=20.x.x
    def install_req_from_parsed_requirement(x):
        return x

# read your requirements.
install_reqs = parse_requirements(requirements_path, session=False)
# for pip==21.x.x convert ParsedRequirement into InstallRequirement.
install_reqs = [install_req_from_parsed_requirement(req) for req in install_reqs]
```

It offers transparent compatibility between pip versions. Moreover, it is quite useful if you need to use InstallRequirement methods and properties, such as req, original_link or match_markers().